# Updating a file in a zip archive

Tags: java, zip

I want to update a file inside a zip archive without the need to create a new archive. I am aware that it could be done by creating a new archive, coping over all other files and add the changed one in.

Here is the code to demonstrate the issue. The first section creates the initial zip archive containing one file with the content `Hello world!`. The second section should replace that content with `Bye, bye!`. The last section is unpacking the zip again so that the content can be expected:

```
try {
    // Create the initial zip archive with the original file content
    File file1 = new File(ReplaceFileInZipDemo.class.getResource("/helloworld.txt").toURI());
    File zipFile = new File("output.zip");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file1.getName());
    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    fis.close();
    zipOut.close();
    fos.close();

    // Replace the original file content with a different file content, updating the file.
    File file2 = new File(ReplaceFileInZipDemo.class.getResource("/goodbyeworld.txt").toURI());
    Path zipfile = zipFile.toPath();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, null);
    Path pathInZipfile = fs.getPath(file1.getName());
    Files.copy(file2.toPath() , pathInZipfile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );

    // Extract the content of the updated file
    String destinationDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File targetDir = new File(destinationDir);
    ZipInputStream i = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    System.out.println("Original file content:");
    Files.readAllLines(file1.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    System.out.println("Expected replaced file content");
    Files.readAllLines(file2.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    while ((entry = i.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        File destFile = new File(targetDir, entry.getName());
        String name = destFile.getAbsolutePath();
        File f = new File(name);
        try (OutputStream o = Files.newOutputStream(f.toPath())) {
            IOUtils.copy(i, o);
        }
        System.out.println("Content of extracted file " + name);
        Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output that I get is this:

```
Original file content:
Hello world!
Expected replaced file content
Bye, bye!
Content of extracted file /tmp/helloworld.txt
Hello world!
```

The only reason that I could imagine this is not working as expected is because the content of the replacement comes from a file with a different name than in the archive. But when adding `Files.delete(pathInZipfile);` to remove the original file completely it is still there.

How can I replace the content of a file in an archive with the content of another file?